# combine two different dimension of dataframes to one dataframe

Tags: r

I have a problem to combine two different dimension dataframes which each dataframe has huge rows. Let's say, the sample of my dataframes are d and e, and new expected dataframe is de. I would like  to make pair between all value in same row both in d and e, and construct those pairs in a new dataframe (de). Any idea/help for solving my problem is really appreciated. Thanks

```
> d <- data.frame(v1 = c(1,3,5), v2 = c(2,4,6))
> d
  v1 v2
1  1  2
2  3  4
3  5  6

> e <- data.frame(v1 = c(11, 14), v2 = c(12,15), v3=c(13,16))
> e
  v1 v2 v3
1 11 12 13
2 14 15 16


> de <- data.frame(x = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4), y = c(11,12,13,11,12,13,14,15,16,14,15,16))
> de
   x  y
1  1 11
2  1 12
3  1 13
4  2 11
5  2 12
6  2 13
7  3 14
8  3 15
9  3 16
10 4 14
11 4 15
12 4 16
```

Comment: where does 11 in de come from?

Comment: You are right, Raffael; I made mistake during make an dataframe example. The e and de dataframe should be :                         e <- data.frame(v1 = c(11, 14), v2 = c(12, 15), v3 = c(13, 16))   and de <- data.frame(x = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4), y = c(11,12,13,11,12,13,14,15,16,14,15,16))

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to "melt" d and e into long format, then merge, then get rid of the extra columns. If you have very large datasets, data tables are much faster (no difference for this tiny dataset).

```
library(reshape2)   # for melt(...)
library(data.table)
# add id column
d <- cbind(id=1:nrow(d),d)
e <- cbind(id=1:nrow(e),e)
# melt to long format
d.melt <- data.table(melt(d,id.vars="id"), key="id")
e.melt <- data.table(melt(e,id.vars="id"), key="id")
# data table join, remove extra columns
result <- d.melt[e.melt, allow.cartesian=T]
result[,":="(id=NULL,variable=NULL,variable.1=NULL)]
setnames(result,c("x","y"))
setkey(result,x,y)
result
    x  y
 1: 1 12
 2: 1 13
 3: 1 14
 4: 2 12
 5: 2 13
 6: 2 14
 7: 3 15
 8: 3 16
 9: 3 17
10: 4 15
11: 4 16
12: 4 17
```

Comment: +1, but this is a little more concise: `D <- data.table(d, keep.rownames=TRUE, key = "rn"); E <- data.table(e, keep.rownames=TRUE, key = "rn"); merge(D[, unlist(.SD), by = key(D)], E[, unlist(.SD), by = key(E)], allow.cartesian=TRUE)`

Comment: @jlhoward : Thank you very much for your script. I modified and applied it to my dataset, and it's work.

Comment: @AnandaMahto: Very nice! I was not aware of the `keep.rownames` parameter. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If your data are numeric, like they are in this example, this is pretty straightforward in base R too. Conceptually this is the same as @jlhoward's answer: get your data into a long format, and merge:

```
merge(cbind(id = rownames(d), stack(d)), 
      cbind(id = rownames(e), stack(e)), 
      by = "id")[c("values.x", "values.y")]
#    values.x values.y
# 1         1       11
# 2         1       12
# 3         1       13
# 4         2       11
# 5         2       12
# 6         2       13
# 7         3       14
# 8         3       15
# 9         3       16
# 10        4       14
# 11        4       15
# 12        4       16
```

Or, with the "reshape2" package:

```
merge(melt(as.matrix(d)), 
      melt(as.matrix(e)), 
      by = "Var1")[c("value.x", "value.y")]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I also tried to apply your script on my dataset, in it's work well. Previously, I tried using merge(), but I didn't come to develop merge() such as you suggested.